# Extracting urls from multiple firefox tabs, comparing and editing them in imacros firefox

Tags: firefox, comparison, imacros, extract

i'm new here, and i'm a beginner in programming.

I'm trying to create a macro (firefox) that will extract the urls from all the tabs opened, compare them and close the second tab t=2 if it's a duplicate, if not do nothing.

For example:

I want to compare the url from tab 2 with: `/a/b_c_22222222_d.html` to all the other urls from the other tabs in the form : `/a/b_c_xxxxxxx_d.html` and then be able to close the tab t=2 if it's duplicate.

Comment: Sounds great. Is there a question here?

Comment: sorry i don't speak english verry well
and i don' know how to do it
can someone help me?

Comment: Stack Overflow does not exist to hand-hold through development. You need to do your own research and work. If you hit a particular problem, please post it. Otherwise, this question is simply too broad.

Comment: ok ive done my macro
i know how to extract and save in a csv file
but i do'nt know how to do the comparaison
i'm not a pro in programation
that's all
if u can help me it well be greatfuul
i just need to do the comparaison between the two extractions

Comment: You need to show your code and ask a *specific* question about it. See "How to ask" in the Help section.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for Firefox ‘iMacros’ extension is to use the js-script like this:

```
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
    .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
    .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
    .rootTreeItem
    .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
    .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
var browser = mainWindow.gBrowser;
var urlTab2 = browser.getBrowserAtIndex(1).currentURI.spec;
for (i = 0; i < browser.browsers.length; i++) {
    if (i != 1) {
        if (urlTab2 == browser.getBrowserAtIndex(i).currentURI.spec) {
            browser.selectedTab = browser.tabContainer.childNodes[1];
            browser.removeCurrentTab();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```